# Beginner: Soap Request Response call from java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I try to do a SOAP request and get SOAP response by Java, and then call it from the JSP page.  I researched many sites, and try many ways, it doesn't seem to able to get it working.

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.mysitename.com/mysoaprequest.wsdl");
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;
```

....

Can I just create a wsdl file with the soap request xml inside?

I read something about Web Service, do I have to get some Web Service working to make it work?

I use some wsdl to test http://www.webservicex.net/AustralianPostCode.asmx?WSDL

I kept getting this error

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://www.webservicex.net/AustralianPostCode.asmx?WSDL

If anyone can point me to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

---

This is the actual soap request I need to make

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.application.tvcc.dmv.ca.gov/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:getNewCourseCompletion>
            <arg0>
                <userDto>
                    <password>********</password>
                    <userId>anyone@somecourt.com</userId>
                </userDto>
            </arg0>
        </ser:getNewCourseCompletion>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: have you tried to use some libraries that do that work for you? At least you can use some http library to send request to the server, because soap request is a simple http request which 'body' contains xml according to the soap protocol

Comment: I updated with the actual soap request I need to make.  I've never done a soap request before, so I try to research and find something that can work. I try  SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance(); also, but doesn't work for me.  I know there is something I didn't do correctly, but I don't know how.  Thank you

Comment: also you can use the SOAPui program to make test to your WS (is very useful for development)

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL is a kind of menu defining what SOAP requests it will accept, and what it will give you back in return.  You don't actually send a WSDL document to that URL as a request.  If you want to dive into exactly what XML you should send, I would recommend downloading soapUI:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.5.1/

Creating a new project and adding the link you provided:

http://www.webservicex.net/AustralianPostCode.asmx?WSDL

as the initial WSDL (you should see the box in SoapUI).  It will then generate the kinds of requests that you can send that web service, and let you fill in the blanks and send it along.

If you want to do that from Java code, you have to pick a web service platform like JAX-WS and have it generate the Java code that forms the requests and sends them along.  Take a look at some JAX-WS tutorials.

Comment: Here's a halfway decent tutorial:  http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world

Comment: @IanMcLaird That's a good resource for this kind of question.  Poster just needs to follow the "Developing WebService Client" portion.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late, but I'll throw an answer out there anyway.

What you want to do is auto-generate Java code for this web service.  I'll demonstrate using the WSDL you referenced: http://www.webservicex.net/AustralianPostCode.asmx?WSDL

In Java, the tool to auto-generate the code is `wsimport`.  You'll want to use something like this:

```
wsimport http://www.webservicex.net/AustralianPostCode.asmx?WSDL -p com.company.whateveruwant -d . -keep
```

This will put the code you want in the specified package (here `com.company.whateveruwant`).

From there, all you have to do is simply invoke the SOAP method like a normal Java library:

```
package com.company.whateveruwant;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AustralianPostCodeTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    AustralianPostCodeSoap soap = new AustralianPostCode().getAustralianPostCodeSoap();
    String response = soap.getAustralianPostCodeByLocation("Collinswood");
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

This prints out:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Location>Collinswood</Location>
    <PostCode> SA 5081</PostCode>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is a very old and very difficult protocol (there are many blogs that tell you why soap is a complete mess), well, if you can, try REST (like RESTeasy framework). But if you have to use soap, you can use AXIS (i use AXIS1 because there are many legacy apps that use that Library), i don't have any experience with AXIS2, so here is the hint's to make clients:

1) You have to add to your classpath the axis library (in linux like the following example):

```
env AXISCLASSPATH=~/axis-1_4/lib/axis.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/jaxrpc.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/saaj.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/xml-apis.jar:~/axis-1_4/lib/xercesImpl.jar:~/wsdl4j-1_6_2/lib/wsdl4j.jar
```

2) Then you can create the client/server like:

```
java -classpath $AXISCLASSPATH org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java --server-side example.wsdl
```

The --server-side make that axis create the wsdl files for deploy and undeploy the server layer, if you want to create a client, remove it.

3) Now you have a folder like com/example/server/.java
4) In the Impl file (like ExampleImpl.java) you have the methods that you have to impl to do some with the WS (in the server side).

5) If you want to consume the WS, you have to do some like:

```
EngineConfiguration engine = EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder
.newFactory().getClientEngineConfig();
SimpleProvider provider = new SimpleProvider(engine);
provider.deployTransport("http", new CommonsHTTPSender());

ExampleLocator sendSmsLocator = new ExampleLocator(engine);
Example example = null;

try {
    example = (ExampleBindingStub) exampleLocator.getExample();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    result = example.exampleMethod(params...);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Well there is many documentation in the axis site:

http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/index.html

Regards,

Comment: I'd advise against AXIS 1, since they haven't had a release in over six years.  It still works, but there's newer and easier-to-work-with libraries out there.

Comment: well, axis1 work fine for us, the soap protocol don't have any update since 10 years ago. If you can choose another protocol i say that REST is the best, for SOAP axis1 or axis2 works fine (but i don't know how to do it with AXIS2) :)